# React table doesn't display row data as expected

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Am trying to build a table and facing a weired issue, row data is displayed as expected but, when I try to build a menu button, the data displays last row's info for all the table rows

```html
<TableBody>
              {visibleRows.map((row, index) => {
                const videoId = row.videoId
                const isItemSelected = isSelected(row.videoId.toString());
                const labelId = `enhanced-table-checkbox-${index}-${row.videoId}`;

                return (
                  <TableRow
                    key={row.videoId as string}
                    hover
                    onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, row.videoId.toString())}
                    role="checkbox"
                    tabIndex={-1}
                    sx={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
                  >
                    <TableCell
                      align="left"
                      sx={{
                        maxWidth: 154,
                        whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
                        overflow: 'hidden',
                        textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
                      }}
                    >
{row.videoId}
                      <IconButton
                        aria-label="more"
                        id="long-button"
                        aria-controls={open ? 'long-menu' : undefined}
                        aria-expanded={open ? 'true' : undefined}
                        aria-haspopup="true"
                        onClick={handleOptionsClick}
                      >
                        <MoreVertIcon />
                      </IconButton>
                      <Menu
                    id="long-menu"
                    MenuListProps={{
                      'aria-labelledby': 'long-button',
                    }}
                    anchorEl={anchorEl}
                    open={open}
                    onClose={handleClose}
                    PaperProps={{
                      style: {
                        maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5,
                        width: '20ch',
                      },
                    }}
                  >
                    <MenuItem key="edit" onClick={handleClose}>
                      <a href={`https://webiste.com/${row.videoId}/edit`}>{row.videoId}</a>
                    </MenuItem>
                  </Menu>
                    </TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                );
              })}
              {emptyRows > 0 && (
                <TableRow
                  style={{
                    height: 53 * emptyRows,
                  }}
                >
                  <TableCell colSpan={6} />
                </TableRow>
              )}
            </TableBody>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have created as many Menus as visibleRows length.
So, when you click `IconButton` and switch `open` state to `true`, all these Menus are open, and the last one is the one shown at the top.
So, you have to find a way to open only the wanted menu.
Like:

```
<IconButton
   {...otherProps}
   id={row.videoId}
>

</IconButton>

<Menu
   {...otherProps}
   anchorEl={anchorEl}
   open={anchorEl.id === row.videoId}
>

</Menu>
```

**Or**, you can move the `Menu` element out of mapping, then one Menu will be open, and use `anchorEl.id` as videoId:

```
{visibleRows.map((row, index) => {
   <TableRow>
      .........
      <IconButton
         {...otherProps}
         id={row.videoId}
      >
   </TableRow>
})

<Menu
   {...otherProps}
   anchorEl={anchorEl}
   open={open}
>
   <MenuItem>
      <a href={`https://webiste.com/${anchorEl.id}/edit`}>{anchorEl.id}</a>
   </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```